# Passing NULL parameter to constructor

Tags: c++, constructor

This is my constructor:

```
    Tree::Tree(char* Pinfo, Tree treeL, Tree treeR){
    info=Pinfo;
    Tree* pointPsubTreeL = &treeL;
    if(pointPsubTreeL){
        cout<<"it is not NULL"<<endl;
        subTreeL=treeL.getCopy();}
    else{
            //it never enter here even if treeL == NULL
        cout<<"it is NULL"<<endl;
        subTreeL=NULL;}
    subTreeR=treeR.getCopy();

}
```

I don't know why but NULL becomes something like an object Tree and then I don't know if the parameter is NULL or not.
In other words, when I reach this NULL element in my Tree, it behaves like a Tree.
Any ideas why and how I could avoid this ?

Comment: `treeL` is not a pointer, it's always an instance of `Tree`. How could a pointer to this instance be `NULL`?

Comment: Trying to read some sense into your question: How do you call the constructor? Are there *other* constructors? Maybe you pass `NULL` but there is a suitable constructor for `Tree` that creates an instance out of `NULL`?

Comment: Well, ok but my constructor HAS to have those parameters as in the test file (for my work) I have : `Tree *tree3 = new Tree("03",NULL,Tree("05"));`
When I do : `if(treeL)`, instead of `if(pointPSubTreeL)`, it tells me that it can't convert Tree object to bool. Then how could I check if the treeL parameter is NULL ?

Comment: If your test file indeed has this line then it's broken. Raise the issue before your professor.

Comment: @Daniel is correct. You may be confused because in Java, you can assign `null` to object variables, but that's because Java implicitly treats those variables as references/pointers. In C++, objects cannot be set to `NULL`.

Comment: You need to show more code for us to be able to help you. Show the definition of `Tree` as a minimum, think about what else might be important for us to see.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking a `Tree` in the parameters which will always be an object. Whenever you pass a `Tree` into this method a new copy of that tree will be created by calling the `Tree`'s copy constructor.

I am assuming that the method you want to have is `Tree(char* Pinfo, Tree* treeL, Tree* treeR)`.

This way passing in `NULL` will work but you will have to pass pointers to the left and right trees. Passing pointers to the `Tree`s will mean that you don't need to have duplicates but will probably require you to allocate them on the heap in order keep the pointers valid.

Comment: I know but my teachers provided us a test file where I have :
`Tree *tree3 = new Tree("03",NULL,Tree("05"));`
So I suppose, I can't put pointers in the constructor. 
Note that I've overloaded the constructor and Tree("05") is supported.

Comment: A possibility is to have a `Tree::Tree(int)` constructor which will be implicitly called by the NULL parameter and sets the state of that tree to a leaf node. This isn't very neat and the line you mention doesn't seem right.

Comment: @MalikFassi I agree with DrYap. I think the code you've been given is wrong. The constructor should use pointers.

Comment: You are right but I think this is a typo by the teacher. Well, I hope so :p.